# How to test localStorage in my react app?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-router, jestjs, react-router-dom

I have a private route in my react app, and when I use jest and run yarn test to test my app, and it shows that in my `PrivateRoute` file there's one line without coverage.
It's line 8 in the `localStorage.getItem` code,

[image]

How do I get coverage for that line?

Comment: Please paste your code as text and not as an image. It makes finding your answer by search and copying and working with your code (e.g. in an answer) easier. :) Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage.getItem` should be spied before expected call:

```
jest.spyOn(localStorage, 'getItem');
```

And asserted that it was called afterwards:

```
expect(localStorage.getItem).toBeCalledWith('access_token');
```

Comment: what is toBeCalledWith assertion and what i the param?

Comment: It is https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tohavebeencalledwitharg1-arg2- . The argument is the same as you use in localStorage.getItem(...).

Comment: I think it can be helpful to note that `mockRestore()` is also needed for spies as a cleanup, what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:-

```
const result = '{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":"bmw"}';

//set json object to storage 
localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(result));

//get object
const value = localStorage.getItem('user');

//remove object
localStorage.removeItem('user');
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your test initializer files:

```
const localStorageMock = {
  getItem: jest.fn(),
  setItem: jest.fn(),
  clear: jest.fn()
};

global.localStorage = localStorageMock;
```

So now you can just use `localStorageMock` globally

`expect(localStorageMock.getItem).toHaveBeenCalledWith('access_token')`

The only gotcha is to make sure that your tests have `jest.clearAllMocks()` cleanup step so the mock is reinitialized for other tests.